# Можно быстро поменять пути у ярлыков через консоль?

Tags: ubuntu, ispmanager

На сервере хранится около тысячи ярлыков на картинки, которые лежат в другой директории.  Так вот директория у картинок поменялась, и нужно поменять пути у ярлыков. Можно ли это сделать быстро с помощью команд в консоли. Или возможно это можно сделать в isp manager 5?

Comment: стандартных средств нет. на каком-нибудь `VB` написать. только если.

Comment: что в данном случае подразумевается под словом «ярлык»?

Comment: Есть файл/папка, а есть ярлык, который лежит в другом месте и указывает на этот файл/папку. При запуске ярлыка открывается этот файл/папка.

Comment: Можно конкретные пути и пример "чё хочу чтобы было"?